# Temperature sensor reading too high and heavily coupled to input voltage

Tags: sensor, temperature, atmel

I'm building a small battery powered temperature sensor gadget thing. I've bread-boarded the circuit and it worked great. I then proceeded to create small PCB out of it.

I've attached the schematic below but the basic idea was to power an attiny85 from a CR2032 coin cell and display the temperature on two 7 segment displays. The temperature is measured using the attiny85s internal 1.1V reference and is connected to ADC2.

The temperature sensor I'm using is the MCP 9700 from Microchip. It has a 10mV/degC temperature coefficient with a 500mV output corresponding to 0 degrees C. It has an accuracy of +- 4 degC which corresponds to a voltage of 40mV.

After testing all other components on the PCB and flashing the attiny85, I then soldered the MCP 9700 to the board. When I applied power, the reading was around 45 degrees C so I figured it must just be residual heat from the soldering process. I left the board un-powered for about an hour. When I switched it on again, the temperature was reading between 10 and 15 degrees too high still. I thought maybe the MCP 9700 I soldered on was dodgy, so I desoldered it and soldered on a new one. I let it cool down over night and it has the same issue.

I also noticed that when varying the supply voltage from 5V down to 3V, the output of the temperature sensor varies by as much as 10 degrees C or 100mV. The MCP 9700 is meant to be quite constant over supply voltage. The same temperature sensors on the breadboard do not exhibit this behavior.

I got the components from Digikey so I don't think they're fake or anything like that. Also, the same temperature sensors work perfect on the breadboard. The code on the attiny85 is correct. I've confirmed this by checking the raw ADC value against the output voltage of the temperature sensor using a Fluke 87V. This leads me to believe that it must be some type of construction issue. I've checked each trace over and over again, confirmed there are no shorts and that the circuit is correct.

I have been banging my head trying figure out why this is. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

[image: Schematic]
[image: PCB]

Comment: Did you try to put some decoupling capacitor next to that sensor?

Comment: No, I explicitly avoided capacitors as the leakage of the caps would completely ruin the battery life. The datasheet does state that decoupling caps are optional and only required in a noisy environment.

Comment: And what about the ATiny - does that also say decouplers are optional?

Comment: @Andyaka the attiny may need decoupling caps... I don't sink or source any significant current through it though so I left them out (probably a mistake). I'm connecting an oscilloscope as I type this so will include some screenshots of everything soon.

Comment: Leakage of ceramic caps is negligible compared to power consumption of MCU, sensor and 7-segment LED display.

Comment: You are afraid the nA, if not pA of a well chosen ceramic are going to win, at all, from any active component, let alone the self discharge inherent in any battery chemistry? You need to think again. Not to mention home etched and hand soldered PCBs,  their contamination and trace-to-trace resistance being well below the giga-Ohms you seem to hope they are.

Comment: @Chupacabras The attiny spends something like 99% of its time sleeping. Current during sleep is around 200nA. Leakage of even 1uA will swamp this and significantly decrease the battery life.

Comment: Where did you take that number from? Leakage 1uA?

Comment: @Asmyldof fair enough. COuld this cause an extra 100-150mV on the output of the temperature sensor though?

Comment: What is the offset error and gain error of the ADC inside the ATTiny? What is the drift in the 1.1 volt reference versus power rail and temperature? How many LSbs of the ADC equates to 1 degC change in the output of the MCP9700?

Comment: @Andyaka I measured the output voltage using my trusty Fluke 87V. Ignoring the micro completely, the output voltage is around 100-150mV too high.

Comment: @Chupacabras Just a typical value I've read. I'm not at all well versed in this sort of thing. Even if it's 200nA that basically halves the battery life.

Comment: Where exactly did you read it? Could you give some link? I'd like to read what cap are you talking about. Standard 100nF cap has about 500Mohm insulation resistance. Apply 5V to that and you'll get 10nA leakage. Just read datasheet for cap.

Comment: I looked to some datasheet now, and 100nF cap has insulation resistance 5Gohm. So it is 1nA at 5V. Way less than your mentioned 1uA...

Comment: @Chupacabras That's good to know, thank you. Damn, should have included some....

Comment: Use some bodge wires and connect some 100nF cap to that sensor. Just to check if it helps, or not.

Comment: @Chupacabras Bodged on some caps and all is working great. Thank you

Comment: Where did you put them?

Comment: @Andyaka One across the attiny 85 supply and one across the MCP 9700. I did both at the same time though so didn't evaluate the MCP 9700 without one.

Comment: Maybe you can evaluate and leave your findings as the correct answer for posterity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested (in the comments) to add some decoupling capacitors.
Adding some 100nF ceramic capacitors helped.
For sensor (between pin 3 and 1) and MCU (between pin 8 and 4).